# How to mark ElasticSearch model field as KeyWord type in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I need to support a Spring app used ElasticSearch as data storage, and I need extract some data filtering by term, like

```
POST http://localhost:1234/library/myType/_search
{
   "query": {
        "bool": {           
           "filter": {"term": {"myTextField": "filterValue"}}           
        }        
    }  
}
```

The problem is fields in Java models are annotated like

```
@Field(type = FieldType.String)
```

not like

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
```

I've tried to google Keyword annotation, but looks like there is a workaround I can't reveal. How to annotate model field for filtering it by terms in a query?

Comment: Which version of Spring data ES are you using? and ES?

Comment: @Val ES version is 2.3.4, spring-web-4.3.3

Comment: Not Spring Web, but Spring Data ES

Comment: @Val spring-data-ES 2.0.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `keyword` data type was added in ES 5, so you won't find it in spring-data-es 2.0.3.

You need to declare your field as `not_analyzed`, i.e. like this instead:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's definitely what's I need.